# Does anyone know how to add or write a new rule for Hand and Foot card game into boardgamesarena.com?

Tags: house-rules

Does anyone know how to add or write a new rule for Hand and Foot card game into [Board Game Arena](https://boardgamearena.com/), so we can play online with distant friends the same rules we would play if in person?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not support for boardgamesarena.com and you will need to contact them about the new rule that you want added.

Comment: I voted to close, because boardgamesarena.com is not a real site.

Comment: @John Fixed that. Not saying it's a good question though.

Comment: This question is better suited at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ . A new rule would count as mod to an existing game and therefore ontopic. Though usually it is about making that mod yourself. Games are written in PHP according to the dev tab. But as far as I know, the dev that made the game is as well responsible for adding content, bugfixes or changes.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are offered an option to add/enable your rules in the game/table creation page, you cannot. This is something that needs to be addresses by the authors of the game module on boardgamearena.

Every game on Boardgamearena has a forum for bug reporting and suggestions.

You could make suggestions for Hand and Foot [here](https://boardgamearena.com/bugs?game=1260).  Check that no one has made the suggestion already, in which case upvote their suggestion.

Eventually the developers will consider if they feel it's a change worth making.  Remember that they are mostly volunteers developing games so may take some time before responding to requests.